# Python Recursion Puzzle: Buying n McNuggets at McDonalds (using 6, 9 and 20 packs)

Tags: python, recursion

I did notice a few related questions to this problem (I also did a little research of this problem on the web). However, all of them are iterative; I am a little baffled on how this problem can be solved using recursion:

```
def is_buyable(n):
''' return whether amount n McNuggets is buyable at McDonalds (using 6, 9 and 20 packs) '''
    if n == 0:
        return True

    #...
    #insert some code or if statement, with call on is_buyable(n)

    else:
        return False
```

As you noticed, this method returns a Boolean. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a specific question?  It sounds like you're asking us to do your homework for you.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really get a good hold on recursion yet. It's just my first time working around with it.

Comment: You are askind the mid term question from the course MITx: 6.00x Introduction to Computer Science and Programming. https://www.edx.org/courses/MITx/6.00x/2012_Fall/about

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recursion works by breaking down each problem to a "smaller" version of the same problem.  In this case, you can insert this code:

```
elif n < 0:
    return False

elif is_buyable(n - 20) or is_buyable(n - 9) or is_buyable(n - 6):
    return True
```

Comment: `is_buyable(5)` is in inifinte loop

Comment: @amit: good point, i've edited my solution.

Comment: Darn! I knew it would be something short and simple. Many thanks!

Comment: @recursive a quick question, you method seems good, but it will probably generate redundant sequence? For example, 35 = 6 + 9 + 20 = 9 + 6 + 20 = 20 + 9 + 6 ..... how can you make the results simplified?

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't quite fit your homework template, but:

```
def is_buyable(n):
    return n==0 or any(n >= i and is_buyable(n - i) for i in (6,9,20))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_buyable(n):
    ''' return whether amount n McNuggets is buyable at McDonalds (using 6, 9 and 20 packs) '''
    if n == 0:
        return True
    for i in (6, 9, 20):
        if n >= i and is_buyable(n - i):
            return True
    return False
```

**Edit**: Using recursion means to have the function call itself on a subproblem of the original one. In this instance, the function checks if at least one of 3 quantities is `True` (buyable):

- The initial quantity minus 6 (after buying a pack of 6)
- The initial quantity minus 9 (after buying a pack of 9)
- The initial quantity minus 20 (after buying a pack of 20)

If at least one of those modified quantities are buyable, then the current quantity (`n`) is buyable as well.

The function also checks if the quantity we have in the first place (`n`) is larger or equal to the number of items of the pack we want to subtract from the quantity, hence the `n >= i` check.

Comment: -1 for giving a blunt answer, with no explanation, to what is clearly a homework problem *(though @amit: no, it's not an infinite loop)*

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I missed the first part of the if statement, I revert my comment.

Comment: Community wiki'd, and added explanation